# how to XHTML-CSS box-model

Tags: css, xhtml

Does someone know how i can make something like this by only using css?
on each side their is 1/5 space.
i have already the html part done.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTPYb.png)

Comment: Something with *width: 60%* and position in the center horizontally. I  would be really helpful though if you would include your efforts in a snippet.

Comment: `margin:0 20%;` works too ... please clarify your question with the code that demonstrate your issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is the html with css

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="block-1">
  </div>
  <div class="block-2">
  </div>
</div>

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  width: 60%; /* left and right 20% */
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto; /* center */
  background-color: blue;
}
.block-1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
}
.block-2 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: do you also know how to add an orange line at the top and bottom off the blue part ?  http://prntscr.com/qh797w     I have tryed with borders but that ruined the whole thing and adding another block section didnt do it either.

Comment: this is what i have now http://prntscr.com/qh7kxr but i gets affected by the left margin any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: i manage to fix the lines but the text is inst left 30 pixeled now  http://prntscr.com/qh7suf

Comment: Website prnt.sc is just showing an image (screenshot), not the code. Please put your html and css on https://jsfiddle.net . Website jsfiddle will show code and result.